# IOS load TableViewCell not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have load a tableView, but it's not smooth. it's lags.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellListsFriend *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellListsFriend" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell.selected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableAttributedString *strFullname;
    if (strFullname == nil) {
        strFullname = [NSString DrawColorForFullname_firstName:contact.firstName lastName:contact.lastName];
    }
    cell.lblNameFriend.attributedText = strFullname;
    cell.lblStatusSentense.text = contact.usernameIsUsing;
    [cell.lblStatusSentense setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:color_status_ShowUser]];
    if ([contact.registerType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Email";
    }
    else{
        cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Mobile";
    }
    [NSURLConnection getImage:contact.linkAvatar showImage:cell.imgAvatarFriends];
    [cell.lblRegisterType setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"777777"]];
    // Rounded Rect for cell image
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderWidth=2;
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imgAvatarFriends.frame.size.width/2];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    return cell;
}
```

I have call 2 methods:
1, get image from DB:

```
+(UIImageView *)getImage:(NSString*)strImageName showImage:(UIImageView*)showImage{
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strImageName];
    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    showImage.image = image1;
    return showImage;
}
```

2, Drawcolor for fullname:

```
+(NSMutableAttributedString *)DrawColorForFullname_firstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName{
    NSDictionary *dict_firstName = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"b47523"],
                           NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17]
                           };
    NSDictionary *dict_lastName = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"b47523"],
                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:17]
                                     };
    NSAttributedString * subString_firstName = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:firstName attributes:dict_firstName];
    NSAttributedString * subString_lastName = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastName attributes:dict_lastName];
    NSAttributedString * subString_middle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" " attributes:nil];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string_fullName = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [string_fullName appendAttributedString:subString_firstName];
    [string_fullName appendAttributedString:subString_middle];
    [string_fullName appendAttributedString:subString_lastName];

    return string_fullName;
}
```

It's load not smooth.

How to I can resolve this problem. It's run lags, not smooth.
****************Edited
I have edited my code, it's smooth but when scroll table, it's reload tableViewCell and change position of cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellListsFriend *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellListsFriend" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell.selected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (contact) {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
            [NSURLConnection getImage:contact.linkAvatar showImage:cell.imgAvatarFriends];
            // Rounded Rect for cell image
            cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderWidth=2;
            cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
            [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imgAvatarFriends.frame.size.width/2];
            [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            //return to the main thread to update the UI
            NSMutableAttributedString *strFullname;
            if (strFullname == nil) {
                strFullname = [NSString DrawColorForFullname_firstName:contact.firstName lastName:contact.lastName];
            }
            cell.lblNameFriend.attributedText = strFullname;
            cell.lblStatusSentense.text = contact.usernameIsUsing;
            [cell.lblStatusSentense setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:color_status_ShowUser]];
            if ([contact.registerType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Email";
            }
            else{
                cell.lblRegisterType.text = @"Mobile";
            }
            [cell.lblRegisterType setTextColor:[SomeMethods_TrinhVM TrinhVM_colorWithHexString:@"777777"]];
         });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your main problem is load the image sync.Change it to async,there are a lot answers about how to load image to UITableview cell async

Comment: I have use dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

Comment: But when I have use this code, when scrollingm it's show position cell wrong :(